# $.ajax get return value from a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, return-value

here I have jQuery ajax calling a .php file that SOMETIMES executes let's say the following

```
echo "hello"
```

Here it is:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myurl.php
        data: data_string,
        timeout: 6000,
        success: function () {

        }
    });
```

I would like to know: is it possible to make the ajax return ERROR and not SUCCESS when something like the previous echo is executed in the PHP file? I mean, checking inside this $.ajax if the php file is executed as I would or not.

EXPLAINING BETTER:
**I get error when the request could not be completed and success when it could. But I would like to get like a return value from this PHP file. If it returns 1, I wanna do something. If it returns 2, instead, I wanna do something else. Hope I explained it better..**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using `json_encode()` within your PHP file. For example:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => 'do_foo'));
exit();
```

Then you can add a conditional within the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: myurl.php
  data: data_string,
  dataType: "JSON", //tell jQuery to expect JSON encoded response
  timeout: 6000,
  success: function (response) {
    if (response.success === 'hello'){
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      console.log('else');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks almost what I am looking for! Just, if I change the js code if (response.success === 'hello') with if (response.success === 'do_foo'), I get always 'else' in the console!

Comment: @Wired It should be working... You'll want to make sure that you're only outputting the JSON, and nothing else. Also, you can add `exit()` after the echo to ensure a clean end to the program.

Comment: In the PHP I'm inside an if { } that when executes calls a mail() function and outputs the json_encode.. nothing else!

Comment: Did you change `array('success' => 'do_foo')` to `array('success' => 'hello')`?

Comment: @Wired console.log(response); within your browser to see what the PHP file is outputting... You probably have something in your response that doesn't match the conditional within your JS. The pattern works, trust me. :)

Comment: In my PHP file there is now: echo json_encode(array('success' => 'hello')); exit();. The JS is equal to the one you posted.. I still get 'else' in the log and not the actual response... I'm getting mad at it!!! PS: how do you post code in the comments?

Comment: What does the `console.log()` output? You can wrap text with \` to show code.

Comment: If I change `console.log('else')` in the code you posted above with `console.log(response)` I get: `{"success":"hello"}`. However what is executed is the ELSE.

Comment: WORKS. THANKS. LOVE YOU <3 PS: what did we do basically? Just to understand better

Comment: @Wired Basically you are encoding your output to JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), which makes it easier to work with. Then, you are just checking for different types of values that you may be responding with depending on the type of success you had. Setting `dataType: "JSON"` tells jQuery to expect JSON encoded data back in the response. :) Let me know if you need more explanation, and I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question make php return 1 or return 2. You can make it return 1 on failure and 0 (which is null) on success. Then you can do this for your ajax return.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "YOUR URL",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(server_response)
                    {
                        if(server_response == 1)
                        {
                            alert("You have made a mistake");
                            return true;
                        }

                        HERE YOU WILL PUT WHAT HAPPENS ON SUCCESS

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myurl.php
    data: data_string,
    timeout: 6000,
    success: function (msg) {
       if (msg != "Hi")
       {
          //TODO
       } else
       {
          //TODO
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use error callback for this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myurl.php
    data: data_string,
    timeout: 6000,
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function() {
        /* Code reacting to error here */
    }
});
```

Also, there are other callback opportunities which you can check out at [$.ajax documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

If you are going to "say" fron PHP that there is an error, this can be done with 2 ways:

You can print in PHP a keyword meaning an error and then check it in you success function:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data == 'error') {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Or, the other way, you can provide with PHP right headers to cause "error". Then you can use the error callback as usual. I would choose this way.

Comment: Yes, but I get error only if I am not able to request the php file. I would like to get error when, for example, my PHP file echoes "Hi!". is that possible?

Comment: How can I achieve the second step?

Comment: @Wired, Just read how to send headers in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php